# adding a custom field column while importing using xpath in solr

Tags: xml, xpath, solr

I am having difficulty importing an xml which does not contain all the required fields.So I need to pass the values of those fields as "NA" or something else.
How can I do it using XPathEntityprocessor in dataimporthandler module in solr.
my data-config.xml is shown below:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" />
    <document>
            <entity name="document"
                    pk="image_link"
                    url="/Users/home/file.xml"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"

                    forEach="/rss/channel/item"

                    >

                    <field column="cp_id"       xpath="/rss/channel/item/productid"  />
                    <field column="title"  xpath="/rss/channel/item/title"    />
                    <field column="description"      xpath="/rss/channel/item/description"  />
                    <field column="link" xpath="/rss/channel/item/link" />
                    <field column="image_link"    xpath="/rss/channel/item/imagelink" />
                    <field column="category_name"        xpath="/rss/channel/item/categoryname" />
                    <field column="sub_category_name"         xpath="/rss/channel/item/subcategoryname" />
                    <field column="brand"  xpath="/rss/channel/item/brand" />
                    <field column="mrp"      xpath="/rss/channel/item/originalprice" />
                    <field column="offer_price" xpath="/rss/channel/item/discountedprice" />
                    <field column="source">sometext</field>
                    <field column="master_category"  name="X"/>
                    <field column="master_category1"   name="X"/>
                    <field column="master_category2" name="X" />
                    <field column="discount"  xpath="/rss/channel/item/availability" />
                    <field column="comparison"  name="0" />
            </entity>
    </document>
```

Here I need to add a source column with a fixed value specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the solution
I used the TemplateTransformer and added "NA" to field column named source.

```
<field column="source"  template="NA"/>
```

for more info on transformers in dataimport handler in solr.Please refer this link:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler